# ASP.NET XSOCKETS Messenger Project Does Not Work

Tags: c#, asp.net

I make an asp.net Messenger WebProject using XSockes.
When run this project onopen and onconnected events its happens.
but wen send message does not work.

what is my fault?

Startup Code:

```
[assembly: OwinStartupAttribute(typeof(XsocketTest1.Startup))]
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.UseXSockets(true);
        }
    }
```

Starter Code:

```
[assembly: PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(XsocketTest1.Starter), "Start")]
namespace XsocketTest1
{
    public class Starter
    {
        private static IXSocketServerContainer container;
        public static void Start()
        {
            container = XSockets.Plugin.Framework.Composable.GetExport<IXSocketServerContainer>();
            container.Start();
        }
    }
}
```

Controller Code:

```
public class Chat : XSocketController
    {
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public void ChatMessage(string message)
        {
            this.InvokeToAll(message, "chatmessage");
        }
    }
```

And JavaScript Code:

```
$(function () {
            try{
                var controler = new XSockets.WebSocket('ws://localhost:34853', ['chat']);
                var conn = controler.controller('chat');


                conn.onopen = function () {
                }

                conn.onconnected = function () {
                    console.log('socket connected');

                    conn.controller('chat').chatmessage = function (data) {
                        console.log(data.Text);
                    };
                };

            }
            catch(e)
            {
                alert(e);
            }

            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#btnSend").click(function () {
                    try{
                        conn.invoke('chatmessage', {
                            Text: 'Calling chatmessage on server and passing a part of the complex object'
                        });
                    }
                    catch(e)
                    { alert(e);}
                });
            });
        });
```

Comment: What is "does not work"? What do you expect to happen and what does actually happen?

Answer (score 0):

The code looks pretty weird...
Take a look here: http://xsockets.net/docs/4/installing-xsocketsnet
And you will see that you have duplicate startup classes... All you need is the "usexsockets" part if you use owin and win8+ (also mentioned in the docs).

Your JavaScript might work but is very confusing since it seems like you have misunderstood the difference between a connection and a controller in xsockets.